I have stepped down as a moderator
This is a post that I've been putting off writing for far too long already.
As some of you may have noticed, flags have been taking a longer time to process of late.
As some others may have noticed, I no longer have a diamond attached to my username.
These two facts are very much related.
Recently, Stack Exchange has decided to update the moderator agreement which defines the moderator's rights and responsibilities from the company's perspective. I have chosen not to accept these changes.
In part it is because of a fundamental disagreement with Stack Exchange the Company's recent shifts in how they see community moderation and the diamond moderator's role in this, but it wouldn't be fair to say that my refusal to sign the new agreement is out of some sort of protest.
The truth is, I'm just tired.
I've been moderating Islam Stack Exchange for over twelve years at this point. That is quite literally a quarter of my life spent dedicated to handling flags and dealing with disagreements, tasks which I have always tried to dedicate my full attention toward. Even for a site as low-traffic and well-behaved as this one (and trust me; even the worst that we see here barely holds a candle to what I've seen elsewhere), that takes a toll.
Moderating has always been a thankless job. This is something that the company and the community managers always used to appreciate, and they would dedicate a significant amount of resources to ensuring that the diamond moderator's workload never became too burdensome. Anywhere from constantly improving tools to ensure the community can handle things without diamond moderator intervention, monitoring individual communities and giving additional guidance when necessary, or even just by being patient, understanding and available when a moderator has a concern. They went above and beyond to lighten the load on the diamond moderators since having burned-out moderators doesn't help anybody.
Ultimately, Stack Exchange was built around the idea of about community moderation; sites were meant to be run from the ground up by the community at large, not from the top down by dictum and fiat.
This… is no longer the case. In recent years, moderators have been treated less as community volunteers and more as unpaid interns, expected to abide by increasingly more policies arbitrarily handed down from on high. I have spent more time over the last few years reporting underage users than handling actual flags, a task which is nothing but menial grunt work that is absolutely not what I signed up for: Diamond moderators may have been envisioned as janitors rather than enforcers, but there's a world of difference between volunteering to clean up the community for the sake of the community, and doing unpaid labour for the Company.
Again, let me reiterate, I am not resigning out of protest. Maybe this was all inevitable, and the ideals that founded Stack Exchange just can't live up to the reality of managing a network of sites that handle literally thousands of questions daily. I don't begrudge the Company for trying to maintain a profit by reallocating and cutting resources, that's what companies are supposed to do.
I am simply resigning because twelve years is a long time to be doing anything, so much more so a volunteer position. And looking at how the Company has been shifting focus of late, I can only foresee the workload becoming worse before it becomes better.
Heck, just the fact that it took this long to write my resignation post should be an indication of how much everything else I have to deal with these days: I'm just not in the same place today as I was a decade ago, with more responsibilities and less time to manage them, and the diamond has just started to take its toll on me as it would anybody after long enough.
Also, let me be clear, I'm not abandoning the site. I still intend to participate as a regular user, either answering questions with my own limited knowledge, or curating with the tools that are available to regular users, etc. If anything, you will probably see me around on the site more often now; as a moderator I preferred to work behind the scenes since it's always been important that this site be seen as a community site — not just as goldPseudo's site — which can be difficult if everyone sees me swinging the diamond hammer everywhere I go.
So you will definitely still see me around, just now it will be on my own terms and on my own schedule. I ask you to be patient with the flagging backlog as the current team is short-staffed; there should be a new election soon to replace me, but I don't have any details as to when.

It is very sad to see you leave as a mod. I agree with you on several accounts.

Oh wow.  Moderating Islam.SE in particular would be especially challenging.  Thanks for years of volunteering!
